# Функция проверки на квадрат

Tags: c++

При вводе координат (2,0) ; (2,2); (0,2); (0,0) квадрат не находит. Я понимаю, что функция не учитывает многих случаев, но почему когда задаю явный квадрат, функция ничего не выдает?

```
bool TryToFormSquare (const Point& p1, const Point& p2,
                      const Point& p3, const Point& p4,
                      Rect& rect)
{
  if ( (sqrt((p2.x-p1.x) * (p2.x-p1.x) + (p2.y-p1.y) * (p2.y-p1.y))) == (sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p3.x)*(p4.x-p3.x)+(p4.y-p3.y)*(p4.y-p3.y)))==(sqrt((p1.x-p4.x)*(p1.x-p4.x)+(p1.y-p4.y)*(p1.y-p4.y))))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((sqrt((p1.x-p3.x)*(p1.x-p3.x)+(p1.y-p3.y)*(p1.y-p3.y)))==(sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p1.x-p4.x)*(p1.x-p4.x)+(p1.y-p4.y)*(p1.y-p4.y))))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p3.x-p4.x)*(p3.x-p4.x)+(p3.y-p4.y)*(p3.y-p4.y)))==(sqrt((p1.x-p3.x)*(p1.x-p3.x)+(p1.y-p3.y)*(p1.y-p3.y))))
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   return false;
 }
}
```

Так как я новичок я не могу отвечать на свои вопросы, в общем вот код корректной функции:
    `bool TryToFormSquare(const Point& p1, const Point& p2, const Point& p3, const Point& p4, Rect& rect)
{
   if (((sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x)+(p2.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y)))==(sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y))))&&((sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p3.x)*(p4.x-p3.x)+(p4.y-p3.y)*(p4.y-p3.y))))&&((sqrt((p4.x-p3.x)*(p4.x-p3.x)+(p4.y-p3.y)*(p4.y-p3.y)))==(sqrt((p1.x-p4.x)*(p1.x-p4.x)+(p1.y-p4.y)*(p1.y-p4.y))))&&((sqrt((p1.x-p3.x)*(p1.x-p3.x)+(p1.y-p3.y)*(p1.y-p3.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y)))))
   {return true;}
   else if (((sqrt((p1.x-p3.x)*(p1.x-p3.x)+(p1.y-p3.y)*(p1.y-p3.y)))==(sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y))))&&((sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y))))&&((sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p1.x-p4.x)*(p1.x-p4.x)+(p1.y-p4.y)*(p1.y-p4.y))))&&((sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x)+(p2.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p3.x)*(p4.x-p3.x)+(p4.y-p3.y)*(p4.y-p3.y)))))
   {return true;}
   else if (((sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)*(p1.x-p2.x)+(p1.y-p2.y)*(p1.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y))))&&((sqrt((p4.x-p2.x)*(p4.x-p2.x)+(p4.y-p2.y)*(p4.y-p2.y)))==(sqrt((p3.x-p4.x)*(p3.x-p4.x)+(p3.y-p4.y)*(p3.y-p4.y))))&&((sqrt((p3.x-p4.x)*(p3.x-p4.x)+(p3.y-p4.y)*(p3.y-p4.y)))==(sqrt((p1.x-p3.x)*(p1.x-p3.x)+(p1.y-p3.y)*(p1.y-p3.y))))&&((sqrt((p1.x-p4.x)*(p1.x-p4.x)+(p1.y-p4.y)*(p1.y-p4.y)))==(sqrt((p3.x-p2.x)*(p3.x-p2.x)+(p3.y-p2.y)*(p3.y-p2.y)))))
   {return true;}
   else {return false;}
}`

Comment: @svjat32 искренне вам советую - никогда не пишите так коряво - ваш код больше похож на регулярное выражение, чем на С++. Вам самому же будет очень трудно читать такие простыни, когда будет необходимость к ним вернуться.

Comment: а как насчет равенства диагоналей? это ведь квадрат, а не ромб. совет @gecube насчет функций тем более пригодится.

Comment: @paulgri, я сам думал насчет равенства диагоналей... Но тут какая закавыка - придется считать все 6 расстояний (4 стороны и 2 диагонали), а затем проверять чтобы стороны совпадали между собой и диагонали тоже.

Comment: Отличный код, так держать.

Comment: @gecube, лучше будет посчитать все 6 квадратов расстояний d12, d13 и т.д., и использовать для этого маленькую вспомогательную функцию, а потом комбинировать эти расстояния в одном выражении вида

return d12==d23 && d23==d34 && ... || ...;

итого: всего 6 переменных, 6 присваиваний, никаких if, один return c выражением, которое будет компактнее того кода, что в вопросе, и выполняться будет быстрее.

Не выдержал, смотри в ответе )) отдаю должное упорству, но может быть полезен пример

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Простыни кода - убрать
2. sqrt() не нужен - равенство чисел и равенство квадратов чисел эквивалентно, а кол-во расчетов разное.
3. Блоки if-else в принципе не нужны. Как только условие сработало - мы пошли на выход из ф-ции.
4. ХЗ, как работает конструкция aa==bb==cc==dd в условии. Я бы писал aa==dd && aa==bb && aa==cc
5. Возможно стоит вынести отдельно ф-цию определения расстояния (или его квадрата) между двумя точками.

Comment: Сравнение чисел с плавающей точкой может не дать правильный результат из-за погрешности, даже если арифметически значения должны совпадать.

Конструкция aa==bb==cc==dd работает заведомо неправильно. Ассоциативность == слева направо, поэтому фактически выражение вычисляется так: ((aa==bb)==cc)==dd. То есть aa==bb дает true (1) или false (0). Затем это значение 1 или 0 сравнивается с cc и т.д.

Comment: почему в таком случае при в воде других координат функция работает?

Comment: @svjat32 потому что на других координатах вам везет

Comment: спасибо, действительно вы правы, все заработало) видимо на других координатах все корни были нулевые

Answer (score 2):

```
double SqrDistance(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{
  return (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y);
}

bool TryToFormSquare (const Point& p1, const Point& p2,
                      const Point& p3, const Point& p4,
                      Rect& rect)
{
  double d12 = SqrDistance(p1, p2);
  double d13 = SqrDistance(p1, p3);
  double d14 = SqrDistance(p1, p4);
  double d23 = SqrDistance(p2, p3);
  double d24 = SqrDistance(p2, p4);
  double d34 = SqrDistance(p3, p4);
  return d12==d23 && d23==d34 && d34==d14 && d13==d24  // 1-2-3-4
      || d13==d23 && d23==d24 && d24==d14 && d12==d34  // 1-3-2-4
      || d12==d24 && d24==d34 && d34==d13 && d14==d23; // 1-2-4-3
}
```

Если в Point поля типа int, то и функция SqrDistance будет возвращать int (корни искать незачем).

Вот только вопрос: а зачем параметр rect?

Comment: это остаток от прошлой переработки, забыл удалить)

Comment: тогда я спокоен))